# Cannot launch node of type [joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher]

Tags: joint-state-publisher, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the latest beta version of hydro installed on Ubuntu 13.04 and encountered this error when going through the urdf_tutorials:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher]: can't locate node [joint_state_publisher] in package [joint_state_publisher]
```

I have installed joint_state_publisher, and checked again:

```
$ rosdep install joint_state_publisher
#All required rosdeps installed successfully

$ rosrun joint_state_publisher joint_state_publisher
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named joint_state_publisher below /opt/ros/hydro/share/joint_state_publisher
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /opt/ros/hydro/share/joint_state_publisher
```

There is a folder in share for joint_state_publisher, but no executable code:

```
$ ls /opt/ros/hydro/share/joint_state_publisher/
cmake  package.xml
```

There is nothing in lib or include

```
$ ls /opt/ros/hydro/lib | grep joint_state_publisher
$ ls /opt/ros/hydro/include/ | grep joint_state_publisher
```

I'm not sure if this is where I should be publishing problems with pre-releases, so please direct me to the correct forum.

Brent

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66733/cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Bjoint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher%5D/) by [Brent Bailey](https://answers.ros.org/users/5196/brent-bailey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-07-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a good place to report Hydro problems.

It's possible that `joint_state_publisher` was converted to catkin, but is not installing its files correctly.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdom1824](https://answers.ros.org/users/40013/jdom1824/) on 2019-02-13**:
I have the same problem but in kinetics, could you correct it?

**Comment by [ixtiyoruz](https://answers.ros.org/users/51823/ixtiyoruz/) on 2020-02-16**:
I also have the problem, is there any solution?